# Counting outcomes in sampling with and without replacement from population

Tags: sampling, combinatorics

Suppose we have a population composed of 100 elements. Also, imagine we have a character with three categories A, B and C with proportions of 40, 40 and 20 in the population, respectively. We draw a sample of 10 elements with replacement while a) order matters and b) order doesn't matter. Is it possible to count the possible outcomes (samples) having 5 number of elements with A character?

**For clarifying and add more details:**
When I toss a coin three times:

1. For counting the possible outcomes, I use permutation with repetition: 2^3 = 8 permutations
2. For counting the successes (say, outcomes with two heads), I use combination without repetition: 3C2 = 3
   Therefore, we have 8 outcomes , three of which with two heads.
   This is an example based on binomial coefficient.

Now my question:
This is the background:
I have a population with 100 elements. I select 10 of them as a sample.
How many samples of 10 are possible to draw from the 100-elements population with permutation with replacement, and with permutation without replacement?
Answer: permutation with replacement: 10^20
permutation without replacement: 6*(10^19)
I  apologize to make a mistake about order in the previous post, ignore it, because order matters here in my question, as it is permutation.

And this is my question:
suppose the proportion of eye color of the persons (elements)in this population is 40% green, 40% blue, and 20% brown. If, say, we have 10^20 permutations (i.e, 10^20 of 10-element samples), can we calculate how many of these 10-element samples have 2 elements with blue eyes?

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you already tried to solve this?

Comment: I second frank's question. Also, how is it relevant whether order matters or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.